# Custom httpClient filter through exception when server is down

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, httpclient

I am new to windows store apps. I am trying to add custom filter to HttpClient it works fine but when the server is down the catch block `return null` which causes the system to through `System.AccessViolationException`. how should i handle that case.

```
  public IAsyncOperationWithProgress<HttpResponseMessage, HttpProgress> SendRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
            return AsyncInfo.Run<HttpResponseMessage, HttpProgress>(async (cancellationToken, progress) =>
            {
                if ((App.userData != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(App.userData.Token)) || App.Get_user()) 
                {
                     request.Headers.Add("AuthorizationHeader", App.userData.Token);
                }
                try
                {
                    response = await innerFilter.SendRequestAsync(request);
                    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                    {
                        ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(typeof(LoginPage));
                        return response;
                    }
                    return response;
                }
                catch
                {
                    return null;
                }

            });
        }
```

Comment: how do you call SendRequestAsync method?

Comment: private HttpClient _client;
  var response = await _client.GetAsync(value);

Comment: then it will fire as it is a custom filter registered with the _client instance

Comment: don't catch the exception in the filter and let it propagate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a server down then instead of returning null you can set up your response variable with an appropriate failure code and return it.

That said, the upstream callers of HttpClient.SendRequestAsync need to handle exceptions and shouldn't crash with the AV. The need for exception handling is explicitly called out in the [SendRequestAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn298657.aspx) docs.